# Controlling the position of Silverlight textbox's caretbrush

Tags: silverlight, cursor-position

I believe the cursor over a textbox is called a caretbrush.
There are times application is run without a keyboard/ mouse (eg: Kiosk), so I will put up a virtual keyboard for the user.

The virtual keyboard appends to the textbox programmatically. 
When I focus on the textbox, irregardless of have any text in it, the caretbrush will always be at the leftmost position.

Is there anyway I can control the position of it?
If unable to do it, guess I just hide the caret brush, otherwise it looks abit confusing especially when u are at the 3rd character but the caretbrush shows on the 1st character.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer already.

txt1.SelectionStart=txt1.text.length

Answer (score 0):

but txt1.SelectionStart=txt1.text.length-1 is only correct